# Measurament error from semivariogram

Tags: spatial, measurement-error, variogram

I am looking at a model to determine the measurement error for a set of measurements of a spatially correlated phenomenon (sea surface temperature measurements) using a semivariogram technique.

For paired reports (reports taken at the same time) the model uses a linear regression of the mean square difference `msd` against distance between the reports and then determines the measurement error `sm`as

```
sm = 0.5 * (intercept + mean(distance) * gradient)
```

For what I know about semivariograms the nugget (i.e. the intercept or the `msd` at zero distance) can be interpreted as a sum of measurement error and micro-variablity and I don't understand why instead in this model `sm` is calculated as the `msd` at mean distance..

Can somebody clarify me this point?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please explain what kinds of measurements these are and what a "paired report" might be?

Comment: Thank you. I am wondering whether you intended to make a distinction between "spatially correlated measurements" and *measurements of a spatially correlated phenomenon.* Since you wrote the former, could you explain how spatial correlation among the *measurements* might arise even in the absence of any spatial correlation of the temperature itself?  That might contain a clue to resolving the meaning of your regression formula.

Comment: @whuber Hi, you are right it's the second concept (measurements of a spatially correlated phenomenon) that I intended to use.. Thanks

Comment: Because sea surface temperatures should vary smoothly, even over large distances, the measurement error itself can be accurately captured by a regression that uses a quadratic spline near the origin; half the intercept estimates the pure measurement error. Therefore a formula like the one quoted here cannot be correctly interpreted as an estimator of measurement error. Could you confirm this is what the formula is intended to do and that you have quoted it correctly? Is this model published anywhere where it could be reviewed?

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes I confirm I quoted the correct model; however this hasn't been published and I received the formula by personal communication. Thanks again